# How Do I Split My String Into Multiple Variables

Tags: python, string, variables

I am reading data from a text file and when I print the content I need to split each word to its own variable.

So far I have:

```
f = open(file='Input.txt', mode='r')
content = f.read()
split = content.split()
print(split)
f.close()
```

Output:

```
['verb', 'verb', 'adj', 'noun', 'name', 'verb', 'adj', 'adj', 'noun', 'name', 'number', 'noun', 'adj', 
'verb']
```

How would I split this string so that every word is assigned to it's own variable?

ex:

1 = 'verb'

2 = 'verb'

3 = 'adj'

...

Comment: unclear. you can't make integers a variable. but one, two, three, etc,,, would work - does that suffice?

Comment: You're already splitting the string into a list, so `split[0] = verb`, `split[1] = verb`, `split[2] = adj`, etc.

Comment: The word is already split up. What's wrong with just using the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the length, it’s rather easy:

```
one, two, three = [1, 2, 3]
```

I’d also look into `namedtuple` since it seems to loosely fit your requirements. However, I feel like you’d be better served by using a dictionary. I don’t know what your end goal is though.

If you could explain why exactly you want to do this, I could probably provide a better answer, since dynamic assignment of variables is typically not a good practice in any language